# Create a 1D array that each cell have two variables?

Tags: c++

How i can create a 1D array that each cells of this array can store two element (i,j)? for example array[0] returns two cells of i, j and array[1] returns two next cells and ... .

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking? Do you want something like `int value = array[0].x + array[0].y;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<std::pair<TI, TJ>> v;
```

Where `TI` and `TJ` are respectively the types of your first and second cell elements.

Then add elements like this:

```
v.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
```

And access them through:

```
v[0].first // first cell
v[0].second // second cell
v[1].first // and so on
...
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a struct

```
struct mydata
{
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

You can then do in your main:

```
mydata x[5];

x[0].i = 1;
x[0].j = x[0].i++;
```

And so on

Comment: This is really more of a `C` answer to a `C++` question.

Comment: `class` would be better than `struct`. But otherwise this is right. I don't see that tuples give any advantage.

Comment: I suspect that `Paul R`'s comment has less to do with the use of `struct` and more to do with the use of raw C arrays instead of `std::vector`

Comment: I think for learning, its better to first understand it using an array. What you use in your code would be preferably a std::vector. Once you know how it works in that model. You can then c++ it up change the struct to a class, and the array to a vector.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished in many ways.  You can use [**`std::vector`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to create the array, and use [`std::pair<T, U>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/?kw=pair) as the element type, where `T` and `U` are whatever type you want.

```
std::vector<std::pair<T, U>> vec;
```

In C++11, you can use [`std::tuple`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/) as well (if you want more than 2 elements per cell),

```
std::vector<std::tuple<T, U, Z>> vec;
```

or you can use a custom struct/class if you want "named" elements:

```
struct Foo {
  T i;
  U j;
};

std::vector<Foo> vec;
```